# How to calculate image's std dev with specific roi size?

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, image-processing, standard-deviation

First of all, my purpose is to implement "Sauvola's Algorithm".

In the algorithm, it needs image's mean and standard deviation("std dev") with ROI like convolution filter.

Already I get the mean value using function "blur" which is mean filter.

However, "std dev" needs a lot of functions which are Blur, Multiply, Minus and Square root.

This step consume is too heavy for my device, "Note3" which is Android device.

below code is the way how to calculate "std dev" now.

```
PARAM_WINDOW_SIZE = 15;

blur(grayF, mean, cv::Size(PARAM_WINDOW_SIZE, PARAM_WINDOW_SIZE), 
              cv::Point(-1, -1), BORDER_REPLICATE);

meanSQ = mean.mul(mean);
grayF_SQ = grayF.mul(grayF);
blur(grayF_SQ, grayF_SQ, cv::Size(PARAM_WINDOW_SIZE, PARAM_WINDOW_SIZE), 
              cv::Point(-1, -1), BORDER_REPLICATE);
sqrt(grayF_SQ - meanSQ, deviation);
```

**In the other words, I want to know the function to get standard deviation each ROI from the whole image for speed up.**

If you know, let me know... please...

Answer (score 3):

Try to calculate it using "Integral image".

An Integral image is a data structure which gives you the sum of values for any ROI in a image in a very efficient way.

You can use this to calculate the std of any given roi by calculating two integral images.

1. I1 = The first integral image is the intgeral image of the origianl image
2. I2 = The second integral image is the integral image of the point wise square of the image (i.e each pixel value multiplied by itself)

Than the formula to get the std will be:

1/n*(S2 -(S1)^2/n)

Where n is the number of pixels in the roi.

S2 - the value of the integral image I2 for the roi

S1 - the value of the integral image I1 for the roi

For a more deep explanation please look at:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table

Specifically go to the line "To compute variance or standard deviation of a block, we need two integral images:" and on.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you. I found an example which is using the Integral image for Average, but I didn't think it can help to compute standard deviation.
I will try it. thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Check

cv.AvgSdv(arr, mask=None) -> (mean, stdDev)

method it should work for you.

Comment: I think that is the function to get mean and std dev from the whole Image.
But thx :)

Comment: You can always select ROI, and then apply this method.